# How can I COUNT rows from another table using a SELECT statement when joining?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

this is the first time I've tried including a row count within a select statement. I've tried the following but including `COUNT(other row)` is apparently not allowed in the way I'm trying to do it. 
How can I include a row count from another table in a select statement, mainly consisting of objects from the first table?

-Thanks

...

```
SELECT
Reports.ReportID,
EmployeeADcontext,
ReportName,
CreatedDate,
COUNT(Expenses.ExpID) AS ExpCount,
ReportTotal,
Status

FROM
[dbo].[Reports]
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[Expenses]
ON 
[dbo].[Expenses].ReportID = [dbo].[Reports].ReportID

WHERE EmployeeADcontext = @rptEmployeeADcontext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing your `GROUP BY`. Whenever you aggregate (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, etc..) you always need to include a `GROUP BY` statement that includes all visible fields except your aggregated fields. So your code should read:

```
SELECT
Reports.ReportID,
EmployeeADcontext,
ReportName,
CreatedDate,
COUNT(Expenses.ExpID) AS ExpCount,
ReportTotal,
Status

FROM
[dbo].[Reports]
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[Expenses]
ON 
[dbo].[Expenses].ReportID = [dbo].[Reports].ReportID

WHERE EmployeeADcontext = @rptEmployeeADcontext

GROUP BY  Reports.ReportID, EmployeeADcontext, ReportName, CreatedDate, 
          ReportTotal,  Status
```

Here is some additional [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) on T-SQL `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You are missing: INNER JOIN [dbo].[Expenses]

Comment: Ah good call thanks... copied it piecemeal after the fact. Fixed now

Comment: @DanK I like where this is going and that would explain the error I get in sqlms but I get "The multipart identifier cannot be bound" on both Expenses.ExpID and Reports.ReportID. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: @DanK scratch that...I added [dbo].[Expenses] under `INNER JOIN`.. Thank you.

Comment: +1 For explaining the need include `GROUP BY` in aggregates. That will probably help me in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You need a group by clause.

Add:

```
GROUP BY
    Reports.ReportID,
    EmployeeADcontext,
    ReportName,
    CreatedDate,
    ReportTotal,
    Status
```

Comment: That is exactly what happen. Not enough practice in SQL to realize it either.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sub-query to return the count. That way you don't need any joins. For example:

```
SELECT
r.ReportID,
r.EmployeeADcontext,
r.ReportName,
r.CreatedDate,
(select COUNT(e1.ExpID) FROM Expenses e1 where e1.ReportID = r.ReportId) AS ExpCount,
r.ReportTotal,
r.Status
FROM Reports r
WHERE r.EmployeeADcontext = @rptEmployeeADcontext
```

Comment: This is semantically different from the question, because it will return `0` if there are no matches.  My guess is that the OP will be happier with this version.

Comment: I am also making the assumption that the columns in the select clause are all in Reports table - except the ExpCount one of course.

Comment: @Donal I will explore this option as well and yes, they are all from the Reports table with the exception of the count from ExpCount. Thank you. Never hurts to try other ways of doing it.